# What alternatives are there for hosting shapefiles too large for GeoCommons?

Tags: data-storage, service-recommendations

I've got a ~500M shapefile I'd like to place where it is publicly accessible and can be found via search. Specifically this dataset is the Bernalillo County, NM assessor parcel and tax database, which would be of some interest to others, but it way too large for GeoCommons. I'd prefer a geo-data repository site rather than a generic file repository (eg, RapidShare and the like).

Answer (score 1):

You can use NextGIS cloud (nextgis.com) for publishing your files. After publishing the file can be shared as:

- GeoJSON
- REST API
- WFS-T service

And also you can create a numerous web maps using this shape file and different styles.

Read the [docs](http://docs.nextgis.com/docs_ngcom/source/toc.html) or watch the [videos](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC0U1GQHn7hbgYkUSnxYaDUQ) about nextgis.com features.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would just use the free services like Google Drive or Amazon with a front end webpage on one of the free website services. Next option if it was part of a project would be on the dataverse (it is somewhat geoenabled). Finally, I think this is within the ArcGIS online free level allowable size (but truthfully I never really know with AGOL).

Answer (score 0):

[QGIS Cloud](http://www.qgiscloud.com/) is a powerful platform for publishing maps, data, and services on the internet. With QGIS Cloud Free, all maps published on the internet are freely accessible by anyone, at zero cost.